# how to add product name in shrt description attribute programatically in magento?

Tags: php, magento

I want to call product name in short description through code. 
I want to apply below short description on all products.
Example,
Buy (product name) at affordable price, Pay cash on delivery in UAE.

Answer (score 0):

//If your description include "(product name)" this string, then it will replace by product name.

```
echo str_replace('(product name)',$_product->getShortName(),$_product->getShortDescription());

OR
```

//Also you can append like as below code.

```
echo $_product->getShortDescription().' Buy ('.$_product->getName().') at affordable price, Pay cash on delivery in UAE.';
```